# Scrape Twitter with snscape

Tags: python, twitter, scrape

I'm trying to scrape sport comments/text from Twitter, but it shows error 4 requests to https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/7jT5GT59P8IFjgxwqnEdQw/SearchTimeline?variables=%7B%22rawQuery%22%3A%22sport%22%2C%22count%22%3A20%2C%22product%22%3A%22Latest%22%2C%22withDownvotePerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsMetadata%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsPerspective%22%3Afalse%7D&features=%7B%22rweb_lists_timeline_redesign_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22blue_business_profile_image_shape_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22verified_phone_label_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22tweetypie_unmention_optimization_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22vibe_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22graphql_is_translatable_rweb_tweet_is_translatable_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22view_counts_everywhere_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22longform_notetweets_consumption_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_awards_web_tipping_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22freedom_of_speech_not_reach_fetch_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22standardized_nudges_misinfo%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_with_visibility_results_prefer_gql_limited_actions_policy_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22interactive_text_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_text_conversations_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_rich_text_read_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_inline_media_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_enhance_cards_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_twitter_blue_verified_badge_is_enabled%22%3Atrue%7D failed, giving up.

```
limit = 1000
tweets_list = []
for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper("sport").get_items():
    if len(tweets_list)==limit:
        break
    else:
        tweets_list.append([tweet.date, tweet.content, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.displayname, tweet.user.description,
                          tweet.replyCount, tweet.retweetCount, tweet.likeCount, tweet.lang, tweet.source])
df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list, columns=['date','tweet','username''displayname','description','replaycount','retweet','likecount',
                                       'language','source'])
print(df)
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBio3.png)

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Was also trying to scrape some stuff from Twitter and from everything I looked up, scraping Twitter is not possible without some workarounds with injecting cookies in an obscure manner.

[Twitter Scraping News](https://cybernews.com/news/twitter-blocks-non-users-reading-tweets-ai-scraping/#:%7E:text=Twitter%20blocks%20non%2Dusers%20from%20reading%20tweets%20over%20AI%20data%20scraping,-Updated%20on%3A%2003&text=In%20an%20effort%20to%20curb,re%20logged%20into%20an%20account.)

It seems that are some workarounds but scraping Twitter got A LOT harder due to the changes being made by Elon.